# Wrong caption with subfigure and tikzpicture

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

when i run this .tex file as `input`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t!p]
\caption{Value}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.7\textwidth}
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\begin{axis}[\axisoptsa]
\addplot table [y=0 , x=row]{file.csv};
\addlegendentry{Ciao}
\addplot table [y=1, x=row ]{file.csv};
\addlegendentry{Bau}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{Tot}
\label{tot}
\end{subfigure}
\\
\par\bigskip 
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[\axisoptsa]
\addplot table [y=0 , x=Row Labels]{file1.csv};
\addlegendentry{Ciao}
\addplot table [y=1, x=Row Labels]{file1.csv};
\addlegendentry{Bau}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  
}
\caption{Micro}
\label{Micro}
\end{subfigure}%
\qquad\qquad
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[\axisoptsa]
\addplot table [y=0 , x=Row Labels]{file2.csv};
\addlegendentry{Ciao}
\addplot table [y=1, x=Row Labels]{file2.csv};
\addlegendentry{Bau}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
} 
\caption{Small}
\label{Small}
\end{subfigure}%
\\
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[\axisoptsa]
\addplot table [y=0 , x=Row Labels]{EMR_VA_classe3.csv};
\addlegendentry{Ciao}
\addplot table [y=1, x=Row Labels]{EMR_VA_classe3.csv};
\addlegendentry{Bau}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
} 
\caption{Medium}
\label{ Medium }
\end{subfigure}%
\qquad\qquad
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[\axisoptsa]
\addplot table [y=0 , x=Row Labels]{file3.csv};
\addlegendentry{Ciao}
\addplot table [y=1, x=Row Labels]{file3.csv};
\addlegendentry{Bau}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
} 
\caption{Big}
\label{Big}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
   \end{document}
```

it works perfectly. 
However, when I insert the second one, with different data, in works but the caption skips a number (from Figure 1 to Figure 3). This does not happen if I put the caption at the bottom, but I really need it at the top.
Does someone know why this happens?

**Edit** I hope now the MWE is within the standards. Pls let me know

Comment: Please make your MWE complete that it can be compiled!

Comment: Try adding the option `figureposition=t` to `\usepackage[...]{caption}` and `position=b` to `\usepackage[...]{subcaption}`. The default of them is `auto` but this includes guessing and this might get wrong in your case, especially since you have different caption positions of main and sub-caption in figures. (See caption package manual for details.)

Comment: Thanks Alex, but it doesnt work for this case =(

Comment: I cannot compile your new document: `! Undefined control sequence. \pgfkeyscurrentkey ->\axisoptsa`. (I'm using TeXlive 2015 w/ updates.) When I try to comment out the usage of `\axisoptsa` and building all the CSV files on my own to have example data, I still get an error: `! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, could not retrieve column 'row' from table '\\
pgfplotstableread@filename@@table@name '. Please check spelling (or introduce n
ame aliases)..`. I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with pgfplots at all, so I need an example document I CAN compile to examine the problem.

Comment: ...and furthermore you even claim yourself that your example code is NOT showing the problem, one need to add further figures for showing the problem. But we need example code which actually DO show the problem.

Comment: @alex thanks for the try. Unfortunately, this post is specific on pgfplots so you need to know how to set csv and other stuff for it in order to help, i can't upload any file with my rank

Comment: @Giacomo Setting up csv files and so on is your job, not ours. If you give us an example document which we can compile successfully and which shows the problem, we are able to help. (You could insert simple csv files in `filecontents` environments.) Currently I cannot compile your document, and even if I could, it wont show the problem. I'm just wasting my time and you don't get help. How meaningful is that? (So I'm out.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your MWE is not complete. I can anly guess, what is your problem. The following approximation of your MWE gives results as you like to obtain (if I understand correctly your question):

[image]

I'm very sure, that this figure composition haven't any influence on `tikz` or `pgfplots` pictures in `subfigure`.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \caption{Value}
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.7\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Tot}
    \label{tot}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image}% instead example-image 
                                                % you can put here tikz 
                                                % or pgfplots picture
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Micro}
    \label{Micro}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image}
\end{subfigure}%
    \hfil
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Small}
    \label{Small}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image}
\end{subfigure}%

\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
\centering
    \caption{Medium}
    \label{ Medium }
\includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image}
\end{subfigure}%
    \hfil
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Big}
    \label{Big}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image}
\end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}

text
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \caption{Value}
    \label{tot}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

**Edit:**  In code I add one more figure to show, that the numbering of figures work properly. I left old image (with only one figure), for new You need just to test given MWE.

**Addendum:** here is example where instead `example-image` I insert some dummy  `pgfplots` images. As can be seen, also there is not problem with numbering of images:

[image]

New MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \caption{Value}
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.7\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Tot}
    \label{tot}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width = 8cm, height=4cm,
                ylabel = {$y(t)$},  xlabel = {t},
          legend style = {at={(1.02,0.5)}, anchor=west},%, legend columns=-1
                  grid,
                ]
\addplot coordinates {(1, 1)    (9, 5)};
\addplot coordinates {(1, 5)    (9, 1)};
        \legend{case 1, case 2}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Micro}
    \label{Micro}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width = 4cm, height=4cm,
                ylabel = {$y(t)$},  xlabel = {t},
          legend style = {at={(1.02,0.5)}, anchor=west},%, legend columns=-1
                  grid,
                ]
\addplot coordinates {(1, 1)    (9, 5)};
\addplot coordinates {(1, 5)    (9, 1)};
        \legend{case 1, case 2}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}%
    \hfil
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Small}
    \label{Small}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width = 4cm, height=4cm,
                ylabel = {$y(t)$},  xlabel = {t},
          legend style = {at={(1.02,0.5)}, anchor=west},%, legend columns=-1
                  grid,
                ]
\addplot coordinates {(1, 1)    (9, 5)};
\addplot coordinates {(1, 5)    (9, 1)};
        \legend{case 1, case 2}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}%

\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
\centering
    \caption{Medium}
    \label{ Medium }
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width = 4cm, height=4cm,
                ylabel = {$y(t)$},  xlabel = {t},
          legend style = {at={(1.02,0.5)}, anchor=west},%, legend columns=-1
                  grid,
                ]
\addplot coordinates {(1, 1)    (9, 5)};
\addplot coordinates {(1, 5)    (9, 1)};
        \legend{case 1, case 2}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}%
    \hfil
\begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Big}
    \label{Big}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width = 4cm, height=4cm,
                ylabel = {$y(t)$},  xlabel = {t},
          legend style = {at={(1.02,0.5)}, anchor=west},%, legend columns=-1
                  grid,
                ]
\addplot coordinates {(1, 1)    (9, 5)};
\addplot coordinates {(1, 5)    (9, 1)};
        \legend{case 1, case 2}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \caption{Value}
    \label{tot}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width = 8cm, height=4cm,
                ylabel = {$y(t)$},  xlabel = {t},
          legend style = {at={(1.02,0.5)}, anchor=west},%, legend columns=-1
                  grid,
                ]
\addplot coordinates {(1, 1)    (9, 5)};
\addplot coordinates {(1, 5)    (9, 1)};
        \legend{case 1, case 2}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

In my MWE I omit all `resizebox` construction, to my opinion they not serve for anything. If you like to have smaller/biger images, adequately change image size (with `width` and `height`).

Comment: Thank you @Zarko sorry for my MWE. You got it right, as I do. The problem is that, as I wrote, when I run a second figure, the caption of this latter, instead of being "Figure 2", is "Figure 3".

Comment: Please provide complete MWE, which demonstrate your problem. I (and others) can only guess, what is going wrong. What you describe in normal circumstances cannot happen! Test my upgrade answer, it confirm this.

Comment: is it alright now? thanks for your suggestions

Comment: I changed my code according to suggestions, can someone find why it still gives me the wrong caption numbering?

Comment: @Giacomo, I can not compile your MWE as is, because I haven't your `csv` files. I suggest you, that you first test my answer and see, if the image numbers are in right order. After this in it replace `example-image` with your real image. If after then you receive error, than is something wrong in your image. If this is case and you need help, ask new question, where you provide your `pgfplot` image with included table `file.csv` and all `pgfplotset` or `tikzset` definition. I will try to make dummy example with `pgfplots`, that you will see, that they as such can not cause your problem.